# OpenCV Colour Detection Error

Tags: opencv, colors, raspberry-pi

I am writing a script on the raspberry pi to detect the majority colour featured in a frame of a webcam and I seem to be having an issue. The following image is me holding up my phone with a blank red image on it. I seem to be getting an orange colour instead.

[image]

Now when I angle the phone I do in fact produce the red colour expected.

[image]

I am not sure why this is the case. 
I am using a logitech c920 webcam that emits a blue light when activated and also have the monitor going. I am wondering whether the light from these two are causing this issue and when I angle it, these lights are not hitting it front on and thus not distributing the image.
I am still not heavily experienced in this area so I would enjoy hearing explanations and possible work arounds for my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Leaving a comment as to why you down voted would be really helpful for asking future questions. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, the down-vote trolls; some do it for the badge, some for venting out. SO should make comments mandatory for down-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that can mess this up:

1. As you already mention, the light from the monitor and the camera.
2. The iPhone screen is a display, so flicker and sync might also be coming to play.
3. Reflection from the iPhone screen.
4. If your camera has automatic control for exposure and color balance etc., the picture quality can change as you move around.

I suggest using a colored piece of non-glossy paper so that you can remove the iPhone display's effects.

Comment: Thanks @Totoro, ultimately I want to apply this to traffic and pedestrian lights on the street so I shouldn't have the same problem I face in my testing.